# How to reproduce behavior of VCL 3.0 vcl_recv / restart in VCL 4.0

Tags: varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I'm upgrading an old Varnish 3 server to Varnish 6.11

This Varnish server was setup to avoid caching large files (over 100mb) using `pipe`. The request was first sent normally to the backend and, if the size from the response `Content-Length` header was over 100mb, the request was retried: `vcl_recv` was called a second time internally with a new `x-pipe` header to the request indicating `vlc_recv` to `pipe` instead of `hash`.  That was the way to do it back then:

added to vcl_recv:

```
  /* Bypass cache for large files.  The x-pipe header is
     set in vcl_fetch when a too large file is detected. */
  if (req.http.x-pipe && req.restarts > 0) {
    remove req.http.x-pipe;
    return (pipe);
  }
```

added to vcl_fetch:

```
  # don't cache files larger than 10MB
  /* Don't try to cache too large files.  It appears
     Varnish just crashes if we don't filter them. */
  if (beresp.http.Content-Length ~ "[0-9]{8,}" ) {
    set req.http.x-pipe = "1";
    return (restart);
  }
```

Now that `vcl_fetch` was changed to `vcl_backend_response`, the `restart` action has vanished. Replacing `retry` with `restart` doesn't achieve the same behavior as the `vcl_recv` function is not called a second time. `retry` only retries the backend request.

Returning `pass` in `vcl_backend_response` suffers from the same reason `pipe` existed: the request will need to be read into memory by Varnish before being sent to client and that's what `pipe` avoided.

My question is: how to `pipe` (send the bytes directly from the backend to the client without any processing) large files using VCL 4.0?

Answer (score 2):

It's doable, but things got slightly more complicated since Varnish Cache 4.0 due to the separation between client and backend threads.

The idea is you need to (1) jump form `vcl_backend_response` to `vcl_backend_error`; (2) create and return to the client thread a synthetic response (and ideally cache it to avoid request serialization); and (3) check the previous response during `vcl_deliver` and execute the restart in the client thread. The following test case shows a working example:

```
varnishtest "..."

server s1 {
    rxreq
    txresp -hdr "X-Large-Response: 1"
} -repeat 3 -start

varnish v1 -vcl+backend {
    sub vcl_recv {
        if (req.restarts == 0) {
            unset req.http.X-Restart-And-Pipe;
        } elsif (req.http.X-Restart-And-Pipe) {
            return (pipe);
        }
    }

    sub vcl_deliver {
        if (resp.http.X-Restart-And-Pipe) {
            set req.http.X-Restart-And-Pipe = "1";
            return (restart);
        }
    }

    sub vcl_backend_fetch {
        if (bereq.retries == 0)  {
            unset bereq.http.X-Restart-And-Pipe;
        }
    }

    sub vcl_backend_response {
        if (beresp.http.X-Large-Response) {
            set bereq.http.X-Restart-And-Pipe = "1";
            return (error);
        } else {
            unset beresp.http.X-Restart-And-Pipe;
        }
    }

    sub vcl_backend_error {
        if (bereq.http.X-Restart-And-Pipe) {
            set beresp.http.X-Restart-And-Pipe = "1";
            set beresp.ttl = 1s;
            set beresp.grace = 0s;
            set beresp.keep = 0s;
            return (deliver);
        }
    }
} -start

client c1 {
    txreq
    rxresp
    expect resp.status == 200
} -start

client c1 {
    txreq
    rxresp
    expect resp.status == 200
} -run

varnish v1 -expect n_object == 1
varnish v1 -expect sess_conn == 2
varnish v1 -expect client_req == 2
varnish v1 -expect s_sess == 2
varnish v1 -expect s_pipe == 2
```

Bad news is jumping from `vcl_backend_response` to `vcl_backend_error` using `return (error)` is only possible since Varnish Cache 6.3.0. Using an older version is still possible to do it, but the solution is a little bit hacky: first you need to jump to `vcl_backend_fetch` and then use an always broken backend:

```
varnishtest "..."

server s1 {
    rxreq
    txresp -hdr "X-Large-Response: 1"
} -repeat 3 -start

varnish v1 -vcl+backend {
    backend always_broken_be {
        .host = "127.0.0.1";
        .port = "666";
    }

    sub vcl_recv {
        if (req.restarts == 0) {
            unset req.http.X-Restart-And-Pipe;
        } elsif (req.http.X-Restart-And-Pipe) {
            return (pipe);
        }
    }

    sub vcl_deliver {
        if (resp.http.X-Restart-And-Pipe) {
            set req.http.X-Restart-And-Pipe = "1";
            return (restart);
        }
    }

    sub vcl_backend_fetch {
        if (bereq.retries == 0)  {
            unset bereq.http.X-Restart-And-Pipe;
        } elsif (bereq.http.X-Restart-And-Pipe) {
            set bereq.backend = always_broken_be;
        }
    }

    sub vcl_backend_response {
        if (beresp.http.X-Large-Response) {
            set bereq.http.X-Restart-And-Pipe = "1";
            return (retry);
        } else {
            unset beresp.http.X-Restart-And-Pipe;
        }
    }

    sub vcl_backend_error {
        if (bereq.http.X-Restart-And-Pipe) {
            set beresp.http.X-Restart-And-Pipe = "1";
            set beresp.ttl = 1s;
            set beresp.grace = 0s;
            set beresp.keep = 0s;
            return (deliver);
        }
    }
} -start

client c1 {
    txreq
    rxresp
    expect resp.status == 200
} -start

client c1 {
    txreq
    rxresp
    expect resp.status == 200
} -run

varnish v1 -expect n_object == 1
varnish v1 -expect sess_conn == 2
varnish v1 -expect client_req == 2
varnish v1 -expect s_sess == 2
varnish v1 -expect s_pipe == 2
```

Comment: Please, not I've edited the answer to add a solution when using Varnish Cache older than 6.3.0.